# Probability of distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A particular question says the average body temperature is 98.2F with standard deviation of 0.7 with normal distribution, allowing us to find probability with z-tables.

However, an additional question asks that if 10 people were selected at random (independent of each other) and X represents the number of people who have body temperatures exceeding 98.6F. What is the probability that at least 2 people have temperatures that exceed 98.6F?

Would this distribution still be Normal, as the parameters of mean and SD still apply, or is it binomial? As there is a fixed amount of trials and success/failure as limits. But then the parameters for n and p, what would be p?

Answer (score 1):

Given the normal distribution, $N(98.2, 0.7^2)$, the probability of someone having temp higher than 98.6 is $\hat{p}=1-\Phi(\frac{98.6-98.2}{0.7})= 0.2838546$.

Sample size is $n=10$ and the probability of at least two people having higher temp is: $P = 1 - P(X=0) - P(X=1)$, where $X$ is distributed as Binomial$(n,\hat{p})$. Thus, $P = 1 - (1-\hat{p})^{10} - 10 \hat{p}(1-\hat{p})^{9} = 0.8238783.$

Comment: The OP question states that the average is $98.2$ while the threshold of interest is $98.6$, so this is an unfair coin.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice, thanks. Will fix presently...

Comment: I dont blame you.  My mom has always told me the average is $98.6$, i.e. my mom disagrees with the premise of this question.  :)

Comment: Moms are usually right :)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the first steps, but I thought the formula for binomial distributions was n Choose x, so how does that work?

Comment: So, what's n-choose-zero and n-choose-1?

Comment: Oh yeh I see. He skipped that step and went straight to the numbers. Haha. So to calculate p you use the normal formula X - mean/SD. And even though its a sample you don't divide 0.7 by the square root of 10?

Comment: Yes, use the parameters of the normal to calculate $\hat{p}$ and then use binomial with parameters $n$ and $\hat{p}$ to get final probabilities.

Comment: I seem to get 0.4285 for p-hat though

Comment: All the details are spelled out in the solution -- compare your steps with these.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You need to use both the Normal and the Binomial in different parts of the computation.